# lazy composition of compare functions

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation

I would like to compose several `compare` function applications. A naive approach would be :

```
let (>>==): int -> int -> int  = fun a b -> if a = 0 then 0 else b

type c = {f1 : bool; f2: int; f3: bool;  f4: int; unused: int}

let compare (a:c) (b:c) =
  compare a.f1 b.f1  >>==
  compare a.f2 b.f2  >>==
  compare a.f3 b.f3  >>==
  compare a.f4 b.f4
```

However, all of them will be evaluated, even if the very first one returns 0 and further evaluation is unnecessary. If there is a way to do this lazily, preferably keeping infix syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OCaml is an eager language, the arguments to a function are evaluated before the function call. You want the second argument to your `>>==` function to be evaluated lazily, and the only way to get this, pretty much, is to use lambdas or the equivalent built-in lazy support.

You can write your function like this:

```
let (>>==) a bl =
    if a = 0 then 0 else bl ()
```

And call it like this:

```
let lcompare (a:c) (b:c) =
    compare a.f1 b.f1 >>==
    (fun () -> compare a.f2 b.f2)  >>==
    (fun () -> compare a.f3 b.f3)  >>==
    (fun () -> compare a.f4 b.f4)
```

Or you can use the built-in lazy facility:

```
let (>>==) a bl =
    if a = 0 then 0 else Lazy.force bl

let lcompare (a:c) (b:c) =
    compare a.f1 b.f1 >>==
    lazy (compare a.f2 b.f2)  >>==
    lazy (compare a.f3 b.f3)  >>==
    lazy (compare a.f4 b.f4)
```

There may be a more elegant way to set up the definitions, but I believe this is the basic issue.